# Testing RxJava infinite interval

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java

I have a simple view that displays currencies as list. App fetches currencies from web service every 1 second. So I have following method in my ViewModel:

```
fun onViewAppeared() {
    currenciesViewStateUpdates.onNext(CurrenciesViewState(true, null))
    Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMapSingle { _ -> currenciesService.calculateCurrencies(Currency("EUR", 10.0)) }
    .doOnError { error -> Log.d("LOG", error.message) }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { currencies ->
        currenciesViewStateUpdates.onNext(CurrenciesViewState(false, currencies))
    }
}
```

Now I need to unit test this behavior:

```
@Test
fun viewAppearedAndCurrenciesRequestSucceeded_currenciesDisplayed() {
    val currencies = listOf(Currency("", 0.0))
    Mockito.`when`(currenciesServiceMock.calculateCurrencies(anyCurrency())).thenReturn(Single.just(currencies))
    viewModel.getViewStateUpdates().subscribe(testObserver)

    viewModel.onViewAppeared()

    testObserver.assertSubscribed()
    testObserver.assertNoErrors()
    testObserver.assertValueCount(2)
    assertFalse(testObserver.values()[1].loading)
    assertNotNull(testObserver.values()[1].currencies)
    testObserver.values()[1].currencies?.let { assertTrue(it.isNotEmpty()) }
}
```

All RxSchedulers set up for immediate. Problem: with test awaits forever when observable finishes subscription, but it will never finish cause it is infinite interval. How can I test it?

Comment: P.S. instead of ugly \`when\` you can use built-in extension **whenever()**

Answer (score 0):

You will have problems running your tests in the way that you have fashioned.

1. Make your schedulers into class parameters, so that they can be injected in the proper fashion, both during testing and production.
2. Use test schedulers instead of `Schedulers.immediate()` because you can end up in a deadlock.
3. Always have your timed operations (`interval()`, `timeout()`, etc) operate on explicit schedulers, usually ones that you have injected.